# Showing Bokeh plots in Binder

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, bokeh, jupyter-lab

I have a simple Jupyter Notebook that produces a `bokeh` plot from a `pandas` dataframe with some associated bokeh widgets. When I run it in both Jupyter Notebook and Lab, it outputs the plot and widgets and is interactive as designed. However, when I put those same files in a GitHub repo (https://github.com/deppen8/leiap_dashboard) and ran Binder, the output plot and widgets are not displayed.

My `requirements.txt` is simple:

```
pandas
bokeh
```

My `postBuild` is also simple:

```
jupyter labextension install jupyterlab_bokeh
jupyter trust survey_dashboard.ipynb
```

Am I missing something in these files to make `bokeh` (with widgets) work with Binder? Or is there something fundamentally incompatible about the bokeh widgets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this example using `nbserverproxy`?

https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sample_repos.html#running-a-bokeh-server-with-binder

Comment: Thanks, juniper. I should have updated. This method was not implemented when I asked originally, but @bigreddot pointed me to this method on Twitter later this summer. Marking this as the accepted answer now for anyone who sees this later.

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh server apps, such as the one embedded in the notebook you link to, required the ability to open and maintain a websocket connection to the client. It's entirely possible that Binder is running behind some sort of proxy such as Nginx, and that they do not automatically proxy websocket connections. You might take things up with Binder support to ask them if this is the case or if there is any network configuration change they can make on their end.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks for the info.